# .htaccess redirect from folder to folder but connected and opened

Tags: .htaccess

hi thanks before read and help i have trouble on here, I want from folder1 to folder2 that they are related to each other but the access links for folder1 and folder2 open so there are 2 links to open, is it possible?

my code

```
Redirect 301 /html/ /folder1/
Redirect 301 /html/ /folder2/

RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^$ http://a.domain.com/ [R=301,L]

Redirect 301 /folder1/ https://a.freedomain.app/?
Redirect 301 /folder2/ https://b.freedomain.app/?
```

i want when domain access http://a.domain.com/folder1/ will open https://a.freedomain.app/?

and open /folder2/ https://b.freedomain.app/

its possible ?

thank before

Answer (score 1):

Check this modified code

```
Redirect 301 /html/ /folder1/
Redirect 301 /html/ /folder2/

RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} a.domain.com
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^folder1/
RewriteRule (.*) https://a.freedomain.app/? [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} b.domain.com
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^folder2/
RewriteRule (.*) https://b.freedomain.app/? [R=301,L]
```

Comment: thanks for your reply but just open root domain and folder1 not open 2 link domain https://a.freedomain.app/? and https://b.freedomain.app/?